# GIFs on PowerPoint 2010 running at a lower frame rate than actual

Tags: gif, microsoft-powerpoint, presentation-design

As the title suggests. I have to put a GIF I made on Flash in a PowerPoint presentation. But when I run the presentation, the GIF runs on a dreadfully low frame rate. Is this issue fixed in later versions of PowerPoint? Or is there a fix to it in the 2010 version itself? Or if there's another software I could use to make presentations which run the GIF properly?

I did search for this, but I could only find forum queries which were unanswered.

Comment: Does speeding up the gif in the software you used to create it, and then re-inserting it in Powerpoint help? Does it reach normal speed after playing through once?

Comment: Sorry for a late reply but that's exactly what I did. Not an efficient way, but worked for the moment. Thanks though!

Comment: I added this and a bit more information as an answer. The jist is that gif frame delays can be interpreted differently. Browsers have some tricks to speed them up, which I doubt Powerpoint uses.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Different applications (mainly browsers, but in this case Powerpoint), interpret frame delays differently. IE, for example, historically [seemed to render gifs slower](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/ieinternals/2010/06/07/trivia-animated-gif-timing/) than other browsers.

As you said in one of your comments, changing the timing in the gif solved the problem. While browsers seem to have tricks for normalizing speed in gifs, Powerpoint's render is probably very basic, considering its basic (or non-existant) support for other image formats like SVG. So this seems to be a case where you need to modify your gif to meet Powerpoint's needs.

The other solution is to convert the gif to a video format and use the video instead. That would be my approach if the animation was very important to the presentation. *(If it wasn't important to the presentation, then I'd actually remove it--personally, I think animations and transitions in slideshows are distracting and pull attention away from the speaker)*

**See also:** [Why is this gifs animation speed different in Firefox vs IE?](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/26994/why-is-this-gifs-animation-speed-different-in-firefox-vs-ie)

Answer (score 2):

Only because it hasn't been mentioned: Are you inserting the GIF file as an image? From experience, this results in slow, laggy playback with lots of dropped frames.

The solution?

Insert the GIF as a video file (Insert > Video from file) then set its properties to play automatically and loop until stopped.

That's it! ;)

Comment: For PowerPoint 16.x for MacOS, this did not work: "PowerPoint cannot insert a video from the selected file."

Comment: GIFs are not selectable from the video insertion window. All graphic file types are greyed out.

Answer (score 1):

I know this is an old question but PowerPoint now supports SVG and I recently tested a PPT2GIFa converted to ascertain that PowerPoint 2016 renders animated GIF images at a maximum frame rate of 50fps (20ms delay).

Answer (score 1):

**Here is the simple answer...**

Just get a newer version of powerpoint.

**A bit more of a helpful answer**

There is a way of accelerating the GIF by going to this website:
https://ezgif.com/speed

Or maybe trying to speed up the FPS in Piskel or Photoshop or something. I don't know *anything* about photoshop so i would just say use Piskel or ezgif

Answer (score 0):

Scribblemacher answer is in my opinion a good one.

I am just puting an alternative if for some reason you need to stick to the animaged gif.

There is an interesting program: http://slidedog.com/ for Windows and there is a mac beta.

Basicly what it does is that integrates quite well diferent media in the same presentation.

You can put for example the first slides of a power point, then put a webpage as a next slide and then again a power point, or video, or a pdf into a seamless presentation.

So you could insert your gif into a simple html document as a slide.

If you go for the video option, you can use VirtualDub to convert your gif into video. http://virtualdub.sourceforge.net/

Try to use a good codec for avi, like Xvid https://www.xvid.com/

Answer (score -2):

Switch to Keynote.

Have been going through this nightmare recently when I was tasked to make a Powerpoint for a client. Powerpoint simply can't handle GIFS, unless playback is being done on an extremely powerful gaming rig. Keynote plays them flawlessly even on terrible systems.

Comment: This doesn't answer the question. It's also possible (or even likely) that the person who asked this question isn't using a Mac, and therefore can't use Keynote.

Comment: I'm a Windows user, so Keynote is no use to me.